# Remove the borders of the cell in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to make the background of only one `UITableViewCell` fully transparent for `iOS7` / `iOS6`.

What I did:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ButtonsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = [UIView new];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [UIView new];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
```

What I get:

in iOS6 everything is OK:

[image]

but in iOS7 there are two horizontal grey lines:

[image]

Is it possible to remove them?..

Comment: Is it grouped table view?

Comment: Yes, it is the grouped one and I have no opportunity to change it to the plain.

Comment: @jailanihabeeb it is pretty clear from the image it is a `UITableView` with `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: And is it possible to implement the separator colour only for this cell - because my tableview is rather big with different sections..